# How to show the sphere in upper-half space is maped to a sphere by $f^{-1}$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I want to show the red line. But from the $(13)$, I can't get the expression of $f^{-1}$ even for $n=2$. I think there's a geometry to it, but I don't see it.

**What I try:** Assume $n=2$, then $p=(x,y),p_0=(0,-2)$, then
$$
p-p_0=(x,y+2),~~~~~~|p-p_0|^2=x^2+(y+2)^2
$$
Therefore,
$$
f(p)=\frac{(4x,4-x^2-y^2)}{x^2+(y+2)^2}
$$
assume $f(p)=(f_1,f_2)$, then
$$
f_1=\frac{4x}{x^2+(y+2)^2},~~~f_2=\frac{4-x^2-y^2}{x^2+(y+2)^2}
$$
next, I should  calculate
$$
x=x(f_1,f_2),~~~y=y(f_1,f_2) \tag{1}
$$
if so, I know what is $f^{-1}$.

But, on the one hand, I feel $f$ like inversion, There should be a geometric way. On the other hand, it is complex to get (1) and I'm a little lazy. So I  let it go.

**PS(2023-12-11):** The (13) of below picture imply
$$
f(p)+(0,...,0,1)=4\frac{p-p_0}{|p-p_0|^2}
$$
So, there is
$
|f(p)+(0,...,0,1)|=\frac{4}{|p-p_0|}.
$
Namely,
$$
|f(p)+(0,...,0,1)|\cdot |p-p_0| =4
$$
Let $q=f(p)$, then $p=f^{-1}(q)$, there is
$$
|q+(0,...,0,1)|\cdot |f^{-1}(q)-p_0| =4 \tag{2}
$$
Obviously, red line is not completely right. Only spheres center $(0,...,0,-1)$ is mapped to a sphere by $f^{-1}$. And this sphere is not contained in the upper half space.

Pictures below is from 177-178th page of [do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry](https://library.lol/main/0A30B69FEAD8267DB0705B4F81764346).

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Could you show us your calculations so far?

Comment: @Deane I have add it in above problem.

Comment: Solve for $x1$ and $fy$ in terms of $f_1$ and $f_2$. The algebra is a bit messy and tricky, but I’m sure you can do it.

Comment: @Deane  I add a PS in my problem. If I'm not mistaken, do Carmo is wrong.